# How convert a XML file to an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have tried to convert XML string I am receiving from a website:

```
   <rosters>
      <roster id_provider="928" id_course="427213" provider_course_code=" " id_roster="0" id_publishing="0" TimeStamp="3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM" provider_publishing_key="8257QP01 ">
        <attendees>
            <attendee id_roster_attendee="" ErrorCode="44" message="Invalid entry for id_license." TimeStamp="3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="NONE" licensee_name=" " />
        </attendees>
      </roster>
   </rosters>
```

I only get the following (plus the XML dump of the string as noted above):

Array contents are as followsSimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) array(1) { [0]=> string(413) "" } Array contents ended!

Please help!!!

Hank

to array using the following code I found else where.

```
   echo "this is my xml returned from webservice <p>" . $xmlresponse . "</p>";
        $xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse); 
        print_r ("this is my xml after going through simplexml_load_string" . $xml_string);

        echo "<p>finally, I go through json encode and decode. </p>";

        $json = json_encode($xml_string);
        $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
        echo "<p>Final array contents are as follows</p>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "<p>Array contents ended!</p>";
```

Here is the link to see the code output

http://nurse411.com/courses/xml/untitled.php

Comment: down voting for a legitimate question? wow! I tried answers from StackOverflow and when they DID NOT WORK, I included them in my question. I am still having the same problem. although I have cut and pasted code from here. I just want help, not negativity. Perhaps there are others less negative that can offer suggestion.

Comment: AS you can see from the output at the link provided, The simplexml_load_string returns nothing. This results in an empty array after json manipulation.

Comment: and what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($xml_string->asXML()));` normally shows you what simplexml could load. You then just traverse that document via that **SimpleXMLElement** you then have according to the documentation: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). As it's an object already, you don't require an array. The **SimpleXMLElement** object is *more* flexible than the array for XML documents and accessing / traversing the data within.

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$xml = '<rosters><roster id_provider="928" id_course="427213" provider_course_code=" " id_roster="0" id_publishing="0" TimeStamp="3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM" provider_publishing_key="8257QP01 "><attendees><attendee id_roster_attendee="" ErrorCode="44" message="Invalid entry for id_license." TimeStamp="3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="NONE" licensee_name=" " /></attendees></roster></rosters>';
$array = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
  SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [roster] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id_provider] => 928
                    [id_course] => 427213
                    [provider_course_code] =>  
                    [id_roster] => 0
                    [id_publishing] => 0
                    [TimeStamp] => 3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM
                    [provider_publishing_key] => 8257QP01 
                )

            [attendees] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [attendee] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_roster_attendee] => 
                                    [ErrorCode] => 44
                                    [message] => Invalid entry for id_license.
                                    [TimeStamp] => 3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM
                                    [licensee_profession] => RN
                                    [licensee_number] => NONE
                                    [licensee_name] =>  
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

> Or you can try with this code:

```
<?php

$xmlstring = '<rosters><roster id_provider="928" id_course="427213" provider_course_code=" " id_roster="0" id_publishing="0" TimeStamp="3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM" provider_publishing_key="8257QP01 "><attendees><attendee id_roster_attendee="" ErrorCode="44" message="Invalid entry for id_license." TimeStamp="3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="NONE" licensee_name=" " /></attendees></roster></rosters>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [roster] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id_provider] => 928
                    [id_course] => 427213
                    [provider_course_code] =>  
                    [id_roster] => 0
                    [id_publishing] => 0
                    [TimeStamp] => 3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM
                    [provider_publishing_key] => 8257QP01 
                )

            [attendees] => Array
                (
                    [attendee] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_roster_attendee] => 
                                    [ErrorCode] => 44
                                    [message] => Invalid entry for id_license.
                                    [TimeStamp] => 3/4/2015 9:51:02 PM
                                    [licensee_profession] => RN
                                    [licensee_number] => NONE
                                    [licensee_name] =>  
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

You can read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I have the second part of your answer in my initial question and, as the question states, the response to print_r is  ===> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) array(1) { [0]=> string(413) "" } . So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I used the second part of your answer in the original question and it did not work. That is why I included it when I asked the question.  The output from print_r when I used your code, was --->  SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) array(1) { [0]=> string(413) "" }. So, that answer is not working.

Comment: @HenryGeiter : I looks like working. Check it here : https://ideone.com/v1sVrf    &   https://ideone.com/uSYiWl

Comment: I do not know what is wrong. I cut and pasted code from my page in question. I have the latest PHP and I am returning the xml from a reputable service (State of Florida run webservices for reporting educational requirements completed).

Comment: @HenryGeiter really I don't know which is your problem, I edit my answer, try with the second code, and see the output, is an array